# Does stopMonitoringForRegion stops only the duplicated region or also the original region as well?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, clbeaconregion

I am working on a beacon monitoring project and currently I am investigating the stopMonitoringForRegion method. What I am doing is, duplicate the original region and start a new monitoring for it. After 30 - 60 seconds, I stop the copied region:

```
[self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:self.duplicatedRegion];
```

So the original and the duplicated regions minor and major ids are same. When I stop monitoring the duplicated region am I also stoping the original region? Because the minor and major ids are same. The only difference in between the original and duplicated region is the identifiers. The original one has a Vendor GUID whereas the duplicated has "testRegion" string.

```
self.duplicatedRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:self.originalRegion.proximityUUID
                                                                  major:[self.originalRegion.major intValue]
                                                                  minor:[self.originalRegion.minor intValue]
                                                             identifier:@"testRegion"];
        self.duplicatedRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = NO;
        self.duplicatedRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
        self.duplicatedRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;

        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.duplicatedRegion];
```

I am asking this because when I stop monitoring the duplicated region, the app doesn't receive any enter and exit region events anymore. In my code I am checking whether the original region is being monitored and yes it is on the self.locationManager monitoredRegions array. Also I never stop the original region. I am just start and stoping the duplicated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical point is to use a different string for the `identifier` field:

```
self.duplicatedRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:self.originalRegion.proximityUUID                                                      
major :[self.originalRegion.major intValue]                                                 
minor :[self.originalRegion.minor intValue]                                                        
identifier :@"testRegion"];
```

If `originalRegion` has an `identifier` of `testRegion` and the duplicated one has that same value, it will cause the symptoms you describe.  This is because **CoreLocation uses the `identifier` field to signal that the `Region` objects are the same, allowing you to replace one object with another.**

To have both regions active at the same time, simply supply a different `identifier` value.

Comment: Yes, the identifiers are different in my project. But at least I am now sure that the problem is not the duplicated region with the same minor and major ids. My question was whether same regions with different identifiers cause a problem. You have confirmed as no. So I accept your's as an answer. Thank you.